# Setting tracking configuration to local branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to work with two repositories, `work` and `personal` in order to keep a synchronized copy of them and be able to work with my project at home and at the work.

So, one project, two repositories.

In order to feel confortable, I've created a new branch in order to to point to `work` remote repository.

```
git switch -c endurance
```

So, I've just created a local branch named `endurance` from current commit.

After that, I've its upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=endurance/main
```

Obviously, I've first created another named `endurance` remote:

```
git remote add endurance <url>
```

As you can see, I've tried to create a local branch named `endurance` tracking a remote branch pointing to `endurance/main`.

At the moment to push it, I'm getting:

```
$ git push
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push endurance HEAD:main

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push endurance HEAD

To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help config'.

To avoid automatically configuring an upstream branch when its name
won't match the local branch, see option 'simple' of branch.autoSetupMerge
in 'git help config'.
```

I don't quite figure out above message. What I got is it's telling that the remote branch's name is not the same of my local branch?

That's correct, my local branch is named `endurance`, and my tracking remote branch is named `main`. But, that's what I've just tried to configure using `git branch --set-upstream-to=endurance/main`, isn't it?

To sum up:

I'm trying to track a remote branch named `main` from remote named `endurance` to a local branch named `endurance`. (`endurance/main <-> endurance`).

Any ideas about what's wrong here?

Comment: Its confusing that you are naming branches and remotes the same thing (endurance) - hard to know when you say endurance are you talking about your branch or your remote.

Comment: That message is expected because the name of the branch is not the same as the upstream (within the remote).... but it is telling you exactly what to do if you do not want to see that error message when you run `git push`  on this branch (I guess the best for you is to set the option, not having to specify `@:main`  every time you want to push.

Comment: That's exactly it's strange for me. I guessed I set it explicitly that I'm aware of I want to track an upstream branch named `main` using a local branch `endurance`. Why do I need to set it explicitly again on push?

Comment: It's a check that git runs _by default_..... it's not like you will find maaaaaaany people using upstream branches that do not match the name of the local branch.... so it's a good check.... _but_ you want to avoid it so........

Comment: You have to change the setting which forces local branches to have the same name as the remote branch. You should change the config called `push.default`  (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-pushdefault). Your workflow seems like it need `push.default` to be `upstream`, meaning you push to the brances upstream rather than what the other options does.